# Не получается установить aiogram 2.23.1

Tags: python, aiogram, pip

Я попытался установить `aiogram` версии `2.23.1`, но получил следующую ошибку (`Python 3.12`):

```
PS C:\Users\nevrm\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\Python> pip install "aiogram==2.23.1"
Collecting aiogram==2.23.1
  Using cached aiogram-2.23.1-py3-none-any.whl (199 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0 (from aiogram==2.23.1)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.8.6.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting Babel<2.10.0,>=2.9.1 (from aiogram==2.23.1)
  Using cached Babel-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2021.10.8 in c:\users\nevrm\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from aiogram==2.23.1) (2023.11.17)
Requirement already satisfied: magic-filter>=1.0.9 in c:\users\nevrm\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from aiogram==2.23.1) (1.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\nevrm\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0->aiogram==2.23.1) (23.2.0)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4.0,>=2.0 (from aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0->aiogram==2.23.1)
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\users\nevrm\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0->aiogram==2.23.1) (6.0.4)
Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 (from aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0->aiogram==2.23.1)
  Using cached async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\nevrm\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0->aiogram==2.23.1) (1.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in c:\users\nevrm\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0->aiogram==2.23.1) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in c:\users\nevrm\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0->aiogram==2.23.1) (1.3.1)
Collecting pytz>=2015.7 (from Babel<2.10.0,>=2.9.1->aiogram==2.23.1)
  Using cached pytz-2023.3.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\nevrm\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0->aiogram==2.23.1) (3.6)
Using cached async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (100 kB)
Using cached pytz-2023.3.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (502 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp
  Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [110 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\base_protocol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_proto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_reqrep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_ws.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\connector.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\cookiejar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\formdata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\hdrs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_websocket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_writer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\locks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\multipart.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\payload.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\payload_streamer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\pytest_plugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\resolver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\streams.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\tcp_helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\tracing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\typedefs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_fileresponse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_middlewares.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_protocol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_request.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_response.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_routedef.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_server.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_ws.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\worker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      running egg_info
      writing aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying aiohttp\_cparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_find_header.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_headers.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_parser.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_writer.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_websocket.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_cparser.pxd.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_find_header.pxd.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyi.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_parser.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_writer.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_websocket.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\hdrs.py.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      running build_ext
      building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\aiohttp
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\nevrm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\nevrm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcaiohttp/_websocket.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\aiohttp/_websocket.obj
      _websocket.c
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(1475): warning C4996: 'Py_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\nevrm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3097): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\nevrm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3238): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\nevrm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3293): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\nevrm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3744): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\nevrm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В aiogram нет пока поддержки Python 3.12, насколько я понимаю. Ставьте более раннюю версию Python.

Comment: На этом сайте принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке. Переведите свой вопрос, или воспользуйтесь [англоязычным сайтом](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Попробуйте [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388920/warning-c4996-py-optimizeflag-deprecated-in-3-12-aiohttp-websocket-c3042)